# Change y labels in plotly python

Tags: python, plotly

I was wondering why plotly package transforms my y-aixs labels to 4μ instead of giving 0.000004 or 4x10^-6 and is there any way around it, except changing it by hand?

My code for formating y-axis:

```
fig.update_yaxes(title_text='y_axis', title_standoff = 3, row=1, col=1, range=[0, 0.000004], gridcolor='lightgray', zerolinecolor='lightgray')
```

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Which version of plotly are you using? I just tried an example I can see the scientific notation in the y-axis. Check [this](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-tickformat) and  [this](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md#d3_format)

Comment: @NoobProgrammer Please provide a fully reproducible code snippet with a data sample.